# How to Change the environment of a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Once I start coding a rails app, I am by default in development mode.

What should I do to change my rails environment to test or production mode ?

can I work in multiple environments simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to run application on production mode type in console

```
ruby script/server -e production
```

TO RUN SAME APPLICATION ON DIFFERENT ENVIORMENT you have to use different ports

like

```
ruby script/server -e production -p 3001
```

AND

```
ruby script/server -p 3002
```

Comment: if I run my app in production mode, it gives me an error like "table posts not available" .. where as its already there and was working during development mode..

Comment: Check your database.yml . The production environment probably uses a different database then the development mode . "rake db:create RAILS_ENV =production" and then "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" should set up the db for production as well .

Comment: @john:- oooohhhh i edit it.that should be different. Thanx john

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are running the application. When you run your tests then they automatically use the test environment. If you are using `script/server` (e,g, using WEBrick, Mongrel etc.) then you can pass the name of the environment to use on the command line e.g. `script/server -e production`.

- If you are using Phusion Passenger then the environment can be specified using the [**RailsEnv** configuration directive](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#rails_env)
- If you are using the Rails console then specify the environment name directly: `script/console production`
- You can create your own environments too. [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/72-adding-an-environment) has the details

Comment: if you want to run both development and production the same time, you must change the port, so that the 2 instances are not trying to use the same one:

`script/server -p 3001 RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: suppose if I run a unit test by saying like  ruby unit/post-test.rb , will rails automatically know that I want to use test environment... after all we are running just a ruby file by a simple ruby command.. how can rails know about this ?

Answer (score 0):

`script/server -e production` for production mode

more in `script/server --help`